How do I access this page on VK which keeps showing 'Security Error'?
Screenshot of the page
How do I fix this and access the page? Was the content deleted? But if it was deleted I'm sure the webpage would display soemthing like 'Page not found' or '404 error' instead.
I used a proxy and tried to login through a different country, but no success. I tried to upgrade my profile's security measures, and even go on the Wayback machine, but nothing worked. I also tried the url on google chrome, but that didn't wok either.
